# Custom RoboDirectives not working in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

Regarding Firebase Test Lab:

I am currently trying to use the `robo-directives` option to provide a custom login to Firebase Test Lab, but it is not working:

- When using gcloud via CLI, like this

`--robo-directives text:sign_in_email_edit_text=test@gmail.com,text:sign_in_password_edit_text=123456,click:sign_in_action_button=`

it cannot find the e-mail field and it does not click in the sign in button. It only keeps adding `123456` in the password field

- When using the web console, providing the same resources as above, it correctly fills the e-mail and password fields, but it does not click in the sign in button. It keeps adding `123456` to the password field

Any tips? I think last month it was working, but I could not find any change in my side. My edit texts are `TextInputEditText` inside a `TextInputLayout`, and my button is a plain `Button`.

Additional info:

- Local gcloud version:

`gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 175.0.0
bq 2.0.27
core 2017.10.09
gsutil 4.27`

- In the firebase console, it logs three times: `A robo directive was not used in the crawl.`

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue only when we selected a `Virtual` device for testing. It works with `Physical` devices...